# .Net Core DI injection Abstract class using Interface in a derived class

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-5.0

I have a derived class which is derived from an abstract class , and the abstract class implements the interface. I would like to inject the abstract class to use the members from the abstract class and interface class . My class looks like :

```
 public interface IStorageTableQueryHelper
{
    IStorageTableQueryHelper Connect(string storageconnectionString, string entityName);
    Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncStruct<T>(Expression<Func<TableEntity, bool>> expression,
        List<string> selectField) where T : struct;

    Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncStruct<T>(string query, List<string> selectField) where T : struct;
   
}
```

My abstract class

```
 public abstract class StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper : IStorageTableQueryHelper
{
    public abstract IStorageTableQueryHelper Connect(string storageconnectionString, string entityName);

    public abstract Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncStruct<T>(
        Expression<Func<TableEntity, bool>> expression, List<string> selectField) where T : struct;


    public abstract Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncClass<T>(Expression<Func<TableEntity, bool>> expression, List<string> selectField) where T : class, new();

    public abstract Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncStruct<T>(string query,
        List<string> selectField) where T : struct;

    public abstract Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncClass<T>(string query,
        List<string> selectField) where T : class, new();

}
```

My derived class

```
 public class StorageTableQueryHelper : StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper
{
    private readonly ITableService _tableService;
    private string connectionString { get; set; }
    private string entityName { get; set; }

    public StorageTableQueryHelper(ITableService tableService)
    {
        _tableService = tableService;
    }

    public override IStorageTableQueryHelper Connect(string storageConnectionString, string entityTableName)
    {
        this.connectionString = storageConnectionString;
        this.entityName = entityTableName;
        return this;
    }

    public override async  Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncStruct<T>(Expression<Func<TableEntity, bool>> expression, List<string> selectField) where T : struct
    {
       //var result= await _tableService.Connect(this.connectionString,this.entityName).ExecuteQuery<T>(expression, selectField);
       return null;
    }
    public override async Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncClass<T>(Expression<Func<TableEntity, bool>> expression, List<string> selectField) where T : class
    {
      //  var result = await _tableService.Connect(this.connectionString, this.entityName).ExecuteQuery<T>(expression, selectField);
        return null;
    }
    public override async Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncStruct<T>(string query, List<string> selectField) where T:struct
    {
        //var result = await _tableService.Connect(this.connectionString, this.entityName).ExecuteQuery<T>(query, selectField);
        return null;
    }
    public override async Task<ContinuationTokenPageResult<T>> ExecuteTableQueryAsyncClass<T>(string query, List<string> selectField) where T : class
    {
       // var result = await _tableService.Connect(this.connectionString, this.entityName).ExecuteQuery<T>(query, selectField);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the class in which I want to inject base class to use the interface implementation too

```
 public class EShopBusinessLogicProcessor : IEShopBusinessLogicProcessor
{
    private readonly IStorageTableQueryHelper _storageTableQueryHelper;
    private  EShopHttpRequestPayload _eShopHttpRequestPayload;

    public EShopBusinessLogicProcessor(IStorageTableQueryHelper storageTableQueryHelper)
    {
        _storageTableQueryHelper = storageTableQueryHelper;
    }
```

}

I am trying to use the .Net Core DI which looks like

```
   services.AddScoped<IStorageTableQueryHelper, StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper>();
   services.AddScoped<StorageTableQueryHelper>();
```

but I am not able to inject it as it says interface does not contain the definition even i tried using abstract class to inject

```
   public class EShopBusinessLogicProcessor : IEShopBusinessLogicProcessor
{
    private readonly StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper _storageTableQueryHelper;
    private  EShopHttpRequestPayload _eShopHttpRequestPayload;

    public EShopBusinessLogicProcessor(StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper storageTableQueryHelper)
    {
        _storageTableQueryHelper = storageTableQueryHelper;
    }
```

}

How can i achieve injecting the abstract class into the consumer class ?

Comment: You need to register the concrete class, not the abstract. An abstract class can't be instantiated. Right now you tell the container to instantiate the abstract class when someone asks for the interface

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 2 or more classes which implements the interface can be registered in the DI using the keyname and thats not an issue. I want to use the class which is derived from the abstract class as an DI which can have multiple implementation

Comment: I already answered that you aren't using any keys here, nor have you registered the abstract type at all. You've registered `IStorageTableQueryHelper ` and `StorageTableQueryHelper`. This means you can't use it as a dependency. You'll have to change the registrations or the constructor parameter type

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why dont' you use `services.AddScoped<IStorageTableQueryHelper, StorageTableQueryHelper>();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register the interface with a callback and resolve the abstract class in it. But you have to map the abstract class to an implementation first.

```cs
// map the abstract class to an implementation
services.AddScoped<StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper, StorageTableQueryHelper>();

// then map the interface to abstract class
services.AddScoped<IStorageTableQueryHelper>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper>());

// or register it directly with the implementation
// services.AddScoped<IStorageTableQueryHelper, StorageTableQueryHelper>();
```

Comment: How is this better than `services.AddScoped<IStorageTableQueryHelper, StorageTableQueryHelper>();` ? If anything, this increases the chance of an error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's a more straightforward approach, as I've mentioned in my answer, but I've written the answer to align with what OP asks

Comment: Try *identical*, except for the overhead of the two calls. This makes as much sense as someone asking to put the arguments in different lines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the concrete class as the `IStorageTableQueryHelper` implementation, not the abstract.

```
services.AddScoped<IStorageTableQueryHelper, StorageTableQueryHelper>();
```

The DI container will only resolve the types you've registered. It won't try to find whether one of the registered types inherits from another or implements an interface. What if there were 2 or three classes implementing that interface?

That's why you can't just register a concrete type and inject the interfaces it implements.

The abstract class wasn't registered at all, so it can't be resolved. The following constructor will always fail:

```
public EShopBusinessLogicProcessor(StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper)
```

To make this work, the following registration is needed:

```
services.AddScoped<StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper, StorageTableQueryHelper>();
```

Comment: 2 or more classes which implements the interface can be registered in the DI using the keyname and thats not an issue. I want to use the class which is derived from the abstract class as an DI which can have multiple implementation

Comment: @DineshTripathi I know. This isn't the case here though. You haven't used a key. You haven't even registered `StorageTableQueryAbstractHelper`.  Unless you use a key, you'll have to register the interface along with the concrete class,  or ask for a specific type.